# PHPExcel can't generate data from database

Tags: php, html, wamp, phpexcel

When i open the Excel file message appear:
the file you are trying to open, 'filename".xls', is in a different format than specified by the file extension. verify that the fileis not corrupted and is from a trusted source before opening the file."

The output is like this:
ÐÏà¡±á;þÿ þÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ
>¶@d‹‹dggÿÿÿÿÿ .....

Here is my code..

```
<?php
require_once 'database.php';

include 'PHPExcel.php';

$phpExcel = new PHPExcel();

$phpExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle("My Sheet");

$phpExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
     ->setCellValue('A1', 'Name.')
     ->setCellValue('B1', 'Age');

$qry_table = ("SELECT * FROM MEMBERS");

$inc=2;

while($data_array = mysql_fetch_array($qry_table))
{

$name   = $data_array['Name'];

$age    = $data_array['Age'];

$$phpExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
            ->setCellValue('A'.$inc, $name)
            ->setCellValue('B'.$inc, $age);
$inc++;
}

$phpExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);

header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel");

header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"filename.xls\"");

header("Cache-Control: max-age=0");

$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($phpExcel, "Excel5");

$objWriter->save("php://output");
exit;
```

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: your code appears correct, your headers should prompt a download dialog box, if it doesn't some else is starting your headers on top

Answer (score 0):

Where's your "mysql_query()" to query the database?
Change

```
$qry_table = ("SELECT * FROM MEMBERS");
```

to

```
$qry_table = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM MEMBERS");
```

//Edit:
And you've got a pointer ref. to an a variable which does not exsits
Change:

```
$$phpExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
        ->setCellValue('A'.$inc, $name)
        ->setCellValue('B'.$inc, $age);
```

to:

```
$phpExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
        ->setCellValue('A'.$inc, $name);

$phpExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
        ->setCellValue('B'.$inc, $age);
```

Comment: thanks for correcting, i've done editing it but still have error

and i notice when i add the line require_once 'database.php';
the error shown...

Answer (score 0):

When you get this error, we always recommend opening the file in a text editor and checking for leading or trailing white spaces (spaces, tabs, newlines), or a BOM marker, or any obvious PHP error messages in plain text in the file.

Try saving the file to your webserver, then opening it and see if the same error occurs